# GPUImage - Error at CVPixelBufferCreate -6661

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, gpuimage

Hi I am trying to edit a single image using the new GPUImage setup but I am running into the following error.

```
2014-07-06 11:52:46.966 App[4314:9d07] *** Assertion failure in -[GPUImageFramebuffer generateFramebuffer],   /Users/Desktop/Apps/App/App/framework/Source/GPUImageFramebuffer.m:156
2014-07-06 11:52:46.968 App[4314:9d07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught   exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Error at CVPixelBufferCreate -6661'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e52dfd3 0x38da6ccf 0x2e52dead 0x2eedad5b 0xb9ca7 0x6c481 0xb990f 0xb93cf 0xbbef1   0x6c481 0xbbc67 0x98229 0x61b39 0x98d9d 0x7065f 0x3928e833 0x39294f11 0x39294c97    0x39295a45 0x39295d29 0x393d0bd3 0x393d0a98)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException


GPUImagePicture *lookupImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"BigApple1.png"]];

    GPUImageLookupFilter * filterLookup = [[GPUImageLookupFilter alloc] init];

    [stillImageSource addTarget:filterLookup];
    [lookupImageSource addTarget:filterLookup];

    [stillImageSource useNextFrameForImageCapture];
    [lookupImageSource useNextFrameForImageCapture];

    [stillImageSource processImage];
    [lookupImageSource processImage];

    finishedImage = [filterLookup imageFromCurrentFramebuffer];
```

Comment: I've been battling with the same. Ensure that your UIImage object has a non-CGSizeZero size. That's usually the culprit. Can you post the complete error so others and I can help you better?

Comment: Hi, yeah I switched the code around to the sample from the GPUImage readme and it runs ok. As soon as I put it back to the above then the issue comes back. Both the source image and the lookup source are present.

Comment: Can you try the "imageByFilteringImage:" method directly on the filter obj and see if the same error is thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, I had missed an additional useNextFrameForImageCapture on the GPUImageLookupFilter.

Comment: You also don't need it on the inputs (in fact, it may cause undesirable behavior if you do). It's just required for the filter you're going to be extracting an image from.

Comment: Hi Brad, thanks for the information. So if I have a chain of filters I should only place it on the last filter in that chain?

Comment: If that last filter is the one you're extracting an image from, yes. You only need that for filters you're pulling an image out of. Otherwise, it's unnecessary.